# Distributive property question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I ran across this in something I was reading:

$$
ab(1-\frac{1}{a})(1-\frac{1}{b}) = (a-1)(b-1)
$$

It seems to me that if $ab$ were distributed, you would end up with

$(ab-b)(ab-a)$

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
How does one arrive at $(a-1)(b-1)$ when starting from $ab(1-\frac{1}{a})(1-\frac{1}{b})$?

Comment: You're using $a^2b^2$ rather than $ab$.

Comment: We have $ab(cd)=(ac)(bd)$ and not $(abc)(abd)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
ab\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)=
\left[a\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right]\,
\left[b\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right]
$$
Now you can apply correctly the distributive law.

Comment: we have answered correctly as  we see,+1

Answer (score 1):

you get $(ab-b)(1-1/b)=(ab-a-b+1)=a(b-1)-b+1=a(b-1)-(b-1)=(b-a)*(a-1)$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer